# Can't join Active Directory from another subnet

Tags: windows, active-directory

We have run onto an issue that computers can not join active directory while being on another subnet on our network.

It seems that network configuration is not the problem: firewall is completely open and the computers are set up to use the main DC as their DNS server. It works and both the computer and server can reach (ICMP, UDP, TCP) each other using IP address. LDAP works as well — users can log in after the computer has already been added into AD.

Reading on other forums it appears that the domain name could be the problem. Both DNS Name and NetBIOS name of the AD is simply `sb`. No tld, not even `.local`, just the two letters.

Obviously that's not conforming to the best practices. Could it be the issue? It [implies on the forum](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/166938-joining-a-computer-to-a-domain-on-a-different-subnet?page=1#entry-1012729) that the problem does not appear when working on same network as the DNS server broadcasts some additional info. But one must use AD's FQDN when joining from another network. Unfourtunately, our domain name coincides with an actual TLD so it seems really plausible that this might be the reason.

Should we change the domain name?

Comment: `our domain name coincides with an actual TLD so it seems really plausible that this might be the reason.` Why is that?

Comment: Are you asking why such a name was chosen? I do not know, probably nobody checked what are the best practices and just typed in something short. The name is more than 10 years old...

Comment: No, I'm asking why you think the domain name coinciding with an actual TLD would be the cause of the issue. There's no basis for that conclusion. Also, as Joe stated, if you don't have single-label name resolution, that would be the problem.

Comment: @GregAskew I have linked the forum answer that suggests such possibility in my question. The answer here by joeqwerty kind of confirms that.

Comment: Just because I am facing the same problem, could you tell please what you mean exactly by: *cannot join the domain*? Do you get the window to enter the username/password while joining, and after clicking ok you get some weird error?

Answer (score 1):

There probably is no need to change your AD name. I've seen worse domain names than this.

I don't know what the sizing of your AD is, but if we're talking about 10 devices, then I suggest making it easy for yourself and rename the domain to SB.com or something like that. Before the rename, unjoin all the devices. After the renaming rejoin them. You might be able to script this.

However, there must be a solution.

As far as I can recall from your (not-so-structured) text, you did the following:

- Added the DC (let's call it DC-01.sb) as 'DNS server 1' on the machines (best is via DHCP) and removed all others.
- Verified that DC-01 contains a working DNS for the sb-domain. Try nslookup from a non-domain PC and from a domain pc.
- Verified that you can ping DC-01. Ergo your networking and routing must be ok.
- Verified that LDAP/AD is working on DC-01.
- Resolved the IP-address of the DC-01.

I suggest you:

1. Add your new subnet via *Active Directory Sites and Services*.
2. Add the *reverse lookup zone* in the DNS Management of DC-01.
3. Verify the domain name in the *forward lookup zone* in the DNS Management of DC-01.
4. Verify that Windows marks the network of the computers as Private and Network discovery is enabled. You can easily check this by opening the explorer and selecting Network. At the top of the window a yellow bar will come up if it's not enabled.

Comment: The size is 70 users, 80 devices, so rename might take a while.

Your synopsis is correct, even non-domain devices on another subnet can resolve requests like `somemachine.sb` using DC-01.sb and LDAP works properly as well.

Thanks for the suggestions I will try them out when I have some out-of-business-hours time here :)

Comment: You could also try some silly stuff with the hosts-file, but that's rather unpractical.

Comment: Yeah, we already have a per-device solution - plug in the computer and join the domain before sending the machine away. I am willing to find a more proper solution now.

Answer (score 1):

With a single label domain and no DNS suffix, the clients you're trying to join to the domain will use NetBIOS based broadcasts to find a Domain Controller. This broadcast traffic is almost certainly being blocked at the router between the subnets. Fix that and you'll fix the problem.

Comment: Oof, I don't think letting broadcasts through to another network is something we consider as a "fix". There must be a more proper fix.